# How to access output from .then statement from fetch request and use it outside of function

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have the function below that sends a fetch request and return a JSON result, I have checked the response and it does return a value that I need, return userid does return me a value, the problem is when I call this function it returns an undefined value even though I have checked it does return a value with the function.

I am looking for a simple solution.

```
function currentloginid() {
    fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=userid', {
       method: 'GET',
    }
)
    .then(function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            var userid = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(userid);
            return userid;
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: For future reference, Java and JavaScript are completely different languages.

Comment: Also, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1). You're doing an asynchronous call, you can't return a value that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `response.json()` output as well. Adding this return should allow you to get the value. If you want to avoid using it in the `.then` function, you should look into [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
function currentloginid() {
    return fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=userid', {
       method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        var userid = data;
        console.log(userid);
        return userid;
    })
    .catch(err){
        //Do some error handling
    }
}

currentloginid().then(function(id) {
  //Do something with it
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, what exactly does currentloginid().then(function(id) {}), do?

Comment: @Tu-AiLe When you're calling external sources, they do not respond right away, so instead of returning the value itself from the function, we return a "Promise" that the value will come. What we do when calling .then is to provide a callback for when the value comes. Essentially we say "get current login id and when it arrives THEN do something in the function provided"